# Lizmap integration in existing page build with Smarty template

Tags: lizmap

We start working with Lizmap an are impressed by its capabilities. Since we want to integrate Lizmap in our existing infrastructure, we are looking for a way to add the Lizmap template to our existing Smarty-templates.

Until now we started with a simple iframe structure, which works, but is not with what we would like to end up.

Is there is a way to integrate Lizmap directly in the code of our template?

Answer (score 3):

I read you don't want an iframe, but I'm suggesting you to change the URL when you call Lizmap. You can put `embed` instead of `map` and you will have lighter version of the Lizmap interface.

You can change the URL like this : `/index.php/view/embed/?repository=my_repo&project=my_project`

Documentation :
https://docs.lizmap.com/next/en/publish/customization/iframe.html

Two examples :

Using the `embed` one : https://www.af3v.org/les-voies-vertes/carte-du-schema-national-des-veloroutes-et-voies-vertes/

Not using the `embed` : https://noe.gard.fr/index.php/moi-face-au-risque-inondation/suis-je-concerne-par-le-risque-inondation/cartographie

Comment: I've loocked at the examples in the links, but all use iframes. We thought not to use an iframe, believing that iframes are an outdated technique. But it seems to be definitely the easiest way to implement Lizmap into an existing Html-page. We would have prefered, integrating the functionality of Lizmap directly inside the code of our page-templates, but we did not find out, which parts of the code we need to integrate.